# WHere does Snowflake stores data like metadata, tables data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

WHere does Snowflake stores data like metadata, tables data and all other data ? Does it uses the Public Cloud which we used to configure while creating account in Snowflake and if yes then under that cloud where it keeps it ? and if no then which cloud provider does it use for the storage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Snowflake deployment has its own metadata servers. You may get more information on what is used for storing metadata:

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-foundationdb-powers-snowflake-metadata-forward/

Based on the additional questions:

The data (micro-partitions) are stored in "object storage services" of the same cloud provides (ie S3 for AWS etc)

Comment: Thanks for replying..Is the Foundation DB also stores the data we stored in tables ? Means whatever tables created by customer and the data stored under those tables are all stored in this Foundation DB by snowflake ?

Comment: No, the data (micro partitions) are stored in "object storage services" such as S3 on AWS etc...

Comment: Ohk in that case it uses the same Public Cloud Provider where we have created our Snowflake Account whether it could aws, azure or gcp...right ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Otherwise, there would be some "latency" issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the data and metadata are stored in the cloud itself where the account is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's deployed on the cloud service linked to the account.

Snowflake consists of following three layers, Database Storage, Query Processing, Cloud Services.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html

Metadata is managed in Cloud Services layer and it's clearly devided from database storage.

Snowflake's core feature is micro-partitions and immutable. Snowflake doesn't overwrite original targets but copies and updates to reference them by Cloud Services layer if something update is required.